# Excel Lookup, Compare, and Return Value

Tags: excel

I have a bunch of outdoor signs with dimensions that I want know their size based on a sign table. Here is this sign table.

[image: sign table]

now I need to fill out the sizes of my signs based on this table. For example, my first sign is a banner with dimension 36, it's larger than 30 (which is the maximum dimension for a large banner) and smaller than 40, so it should return x-larger. Similar for all the rest of the signs, the second pylon for example, 99 is in between 70 and 100, so it should return medium. Here is my outdoor sign list.

I'm not sure what functions/combo I should use to do this, please help and thanks!!

[image: my outdoor signs]

Comment: [Why Not Images of Code and Sample Data](http://tinyurl.com/kdxb7le)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Adjust your ranges as necessar:

```
=IFERROR(INDEX($A$2:$A$5,MATCH(H2,INDEX($B$2:$E$5,,MATCH(G2,$B$1:$E$1,0)),-1)),"No Match Found")
```

[image]

Comment: You might have to wrap the whole formula in an [IFERROR](https://support.office.com/en-us/article/IFERROR-function-F59BACDC-78BD-4924-91DF-A869D0B08CD5)(<formula>, A$2) in order to catch the descending order matches that are larger then the maximum (channel letters, 115).

Comment: I'm unclear on why that requires CSE. While that does not harm the formula, I do not believe it is necessary.

Comment: Ha! You are right. I must be on auto-pilot mode today. I had just written a similar INDEX formula on a previous post where it DID need to be used and wasn't thinking.